# Elixir decorators with function headers and defaults

Tags: elixir

I'm having an issue where I need to add match cases to a function that has both decorators and a default:

```
@decorate print()
def foo(a, b \\ "b") ...
```

Using an example from the Decorators package this example spits out warnings:

```
defmodule PrintDecorator do
  use Decorator.Define, [print: 0]

  def print(body, context) do
    quote do
      IO.puts("Function called: " <> Atom.to_string(unquote(context.name)))
      unquote(body)
    end
  end
end

defmodule Foo do
  use PrintDecorator

  @decorate print()
  def bar(a, b \\ "b")
  def bar("foo", b) do
    "a is foo" <> b
  end
  def bar(a, b) do
    a <> b
  end
end
```

Warnings:

```
warning: variable "a" is unused
  iex:64

warning: variable "b" is unused
  iex:64

warning: def bar/2 has multiple clauses and also declares default values. In such cases, the default values should be defined in a header. Instead of:

    def foo(:first_clause, b \\ :default) do ... end
    def foo(:second_clause, b) do ... end

one should write:

    def foo(a, b \\ :default)
    def foo(:first_clause, b) do ... end
    def foo(:second_clause, b) do ... end

  iex:60

warning: this clause cannot match because a previous clause at line 60 always matches
  iex:60
```

It throws a warning no matter where the decorator is placed, but if I remove the decorator the module behaves as expected.

Does anyone have a solution for this?

Comment: Your code works without any error. You should recheck your code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FWIW, the package used is [`decorator`](https://github.com/arjan/decorator). It makes sense to give references to 3rd party packages in the question itself.

The issue is induced by something else. The code you provided works perfectly, but it cannot issue a warning that refers to line 64. Here is the example that I have proven to work.

```rb
defmodule PD do
  use Decorator.Define, print: 0

  def print(body, context) do
    quote do
      IO.puts("Called: #{unquote(context.name)}")
      unquote(body)
    end
  end
end

defmodule Test do
  use PD

  @decorate print()
  def f(a, b \\ "b")
  def f("foo", b), do: "a is foo | " <> b
  def f(a, b), do: a <> " | " <> b
end

#⇒ Test.f "bar"
#  Called: f
#  "bar | b"
```

Start the fresh `iex` session or put the code in the project and test from there.

Comment: Yeah sorry this is on Elixir 1.7.4 using the decorators package version 1.2.0. Looking at the releases it looks like this should be fixed in decorators 1.3.1. Guess I better upgrade. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: It makes zero sense, in general, to stay on legacy Elixir versions. It’s 102% backward compatible.

Comment: That's true in general but upgrading major versions may mean upgrading dependencies which may mean API changes. Elixir does have deprecations so is not 100% backwards compatible.

Comment: `1.7.4` → `1.9.2` is not a major and deprecations do not mean incompatibility.

Comment: Ah right that's minor >< and you're right I was confusing hard deprecation with removal. Thanks for the help.